# Специфическая настройка mod_rewrite

Tags: mod_rewrite, php

Здравствуйте
Пробую перенастроить работу сайта (интернет магазина), там много регионов и переключение между ними осуществляется через параметр ссылки http://site.ru/?region=kyiv
Но я хочу перенести отдельные города на поддомены и чтобы перепись ссылок была приблизительно такая :

```
http://site.ru/?region=kyiv на http://kyiv.site.ru/  
http://site.ru/some_category-7/?region=kyiv на http://kyiv.site.ru/some_category-7/  
http://site.ru/some_category-7/some_good.html?region=kyiv на http://kyiv.site.ru/some_category-7/some_good.html
```

Таких городов есть несколько. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как я писал в соседнем вопросе про поддомены -- лучше использовать ДНС для руления поддоменами. смысл в том, чтобы *.site.ru вло на ваш сайт, а дальше скриптом обрабатывалось все остальное. ссылки в любом случае будут генериться скриптом, так что...